# GWT Dynamic page generation

Tags: java, jsp, gwt, servlets

I have written a webpage with GWT which contains auto-generated Hyperlinks. These hyperlinks currently dont point to anything, however, I want them to display certain dynamic information based on the name of the hyperlink. For instance if the hyperlink says iPhone, it should open up another URL with dynamic information about the iPhone which I retrieve from my database. I know JSP/Servlets are used to generate dynamic information on webpages, but how can I integrate such functionality into my GWT webpage?

Thanks

---

Great this certainly helps in giving me an idea on how I can go about my design.

As a follow up though I have a question on how I can access my backend DB. Now I have stored some data in a SQLite DB which I want to be displayed on the webpage. I was able to implement backend access via GWT's RPC, however, it doesnt seem to allow transfer of a ResultSet object returned by a query. How can ResultSets be transferred? In my browsing I have seen a few keywords such as DTO, JPA etc thrown around but I dont quite have a picture on how they will plug in.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...GWT would use rpc to achieve all this. Why do you think you need servlets?

Comment: You are obviously new to GWT.Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/ and go through some examples from the link I have provided.It will be become clear otherwise your question is very highlevel.

Comment: @getn_outchea: GWT-RPC is not Sun RPC (or anything like that). It is based on HTTP, and works with Servlets on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

1. [CLIENT]: add a ClickHandler to your hyperlinks where you execute the following steps:
2. [CLIENT]: retrieve token from hyperlink (i.e. iPhone).
3. [CLIENT]: access the backend (RPC, RequestFactory or normal RequestBuilder) and pass the token (iPhone) to the backend
4. [SERVER]: On the backend (servlet, python, php, etc) handle the AJAX call from your GWT app and return the dynamic information based on the token.
5. [CLIENT]: Display the dynamic information returned by the server call (step 3) in a HTMLPanel or SimplePanel